# How to get the Arquillian Websphere adapter via Maven?

Tags: maven, jboss, websphere, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to set up Arquillian tests for an application running in a Websphere (WAS8) container. For this I used the Maven coordinates I found on [arquillian.org](http://arquillian.org/modules/arquillian-was-remote-8-container-adapter):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-was-remote-8</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, no `arquillian-was-*` artifacts can be found via the two mentioned Maven repositories [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/container/) and the [JBoss Maven Repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jboss/arquillian/container).

Any ideas how I could get a hold of the required Arquillian WAS8 container adapter via Maven? The source code is located on [github](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-was/releases) but it's unclear how to obtain the required JAR files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/WAS+V8.0+-+Remote .

You have to build it yourself because as the link says : "This container implementation is currently not available in public maven repositories." Build instructions can be found on the link. Good Luck ! :)

Comment: I assume the reason is licensing.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was able to build the `arquillian-was-remote-8.jar` and was just about to ask another question about how to set all the container configuration properties... ;-)